# Do span elements in the middle of a word affect a crawler's ability to detect content?

Tags: seo, website-design

I have a site with a heading tag like this:

```
<h1><span class="initial">H</span>andyman <span class="initial">S</span>ervices</h1>
```

I've done this so that I can apply a bigger font size to the first letter of each word.  However, in webmaster tools I see the keyword 'andyman' under Optimization > Content Keywords

Is that anyway to acheive a bigger font size for first letter) without effecting a webcrawlers ability to detect the word?

**Update:**

I can't simply use `text-transform: capitalize` as the element in question already has `text-transform: uppercase;` and I would like the effect to more dramatic than that provided by the uppercase letters of most fonts.

Comment: nice question! javascript is the answer

Comment: @toPeerOrNotToPeer: In light of Google's increasing ability to index JavaScript generated content, I'm not sure that JavaScript is necessarily the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use CSS and the [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3afirst-letter) [psuedo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Pseudo-elements) like this

http://jsbin.com/acagop/2/edit#html,live

Edit to demonstrate multiple words:
http://jsbin.com/acagop/4/edit#html,live

Edit to demonstrate Raffael Luthiger's idea to wrap entire words: 
http://jsbin.com/acagop/6/edit#html,live

```
<style>
h1:first-letter { 
  font-size:300%;
  color:red;
}
</style>

<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

Comment: He has multiple words within his header `<h1>` tag that will only work with the first letter of the first word it's not doing what he wants at all.

Comment: Incorrect it will work for the first letter only. Does not apply to each word and works in all modern browsers http://jsbin.com/acagop/4/edit#html,live

Comment: It's not capitalizing and styling the first letter of each word

Comment: My mistake I thought he wanted it like the jquery plugin or how you commonly see in books. Like the classic fairy tale old english style thing. In that case yeah javascript is the way to go. I've +1 Ellipsis answer.

Comment: This solution could still work if the span would be applied around the whole word. Then span:first-letter could be used.

Comment: @Raffael : That makes sense, css would need to be adjusted since it doesn't work on inline elements. I've updated my answer to include the new idea.

Comment: If the words are being inserted dynamically within the `h1` such as a blog post title in WordPress you would have to hack your code even further to add a `span` tag around each individual word of the title. More work than need be in my opinion.

Comment: @Anagio This is just a point of few. For me adapting the PHP code would be faster than adding some javascript. So for me it would be less work. But yes, for most people adding the javascript would probably be easier.

Comment: The OP is already doing a hack job with the `<span class="initial">`. Doing this in php or javascript is a moot point to argue about. Both would have performance issues, php would slightly effect backend (fixed with caching) and javascript solution would be a bit worse and also slow down client side performance and make FOUC effect. I wouldn't do either personally. CSS Capatalize should have the same effect and be proper English. And maybe the OP can just use an already Capatalized webfont, but again slowness which I don't like personally.

Comment: I ended up just dropping the spans and using the capitalization available in the font but this is the best answer for anyone who really needs the effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery to select the first character and change it on the fly, so crawlers wouldn't see the span.

Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039397/jquery-select-first-letter

**Update:** 
There is a plugin for this feature as well: 
http://812studio.com/initial-letter-a-jquery-plugin-for-making-drop-caps-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to use CSS. You can use `text-transform` like:

```
text-transform: capitalize;
```

Comment: I should have mentioned, I have already applied text-transform: uppercase;

Answer (score 0):

Google is clearly reading the rendered HTML and separating the word because of the `span` tag. Since headers are pretty important to tell Google what keywords are a little more important on your page than others you may re-consider your code to be semantically correct. While you get a nice looking header is it worth it if google sees `andyman` instead of `Handyman`